# How to fix WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation

Tags: jboss

does anyone have idea on how to fix this problem? I am trying to clear the jboss history in my development server.. So whenever I try to run this command >> root@192.168.0.116:/opt/jboss-as-7.1.1/bin$ ./standalone.sh

I will get this error >>WARNING JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.

Does anyone know why this error keep coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are on a windows server, it should be your environment variables that must be pointing to previous JBOSS installations.

Check your Enviornment variables under

```
MyComputer>Properties>Advanced System Setting >Enviornment Variables
```

point the JBOSS_HOME to your current Jboss 7 installation directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices:

1. If you have a **single instance of WildFly/JBoss** on that machine **you must create a env variable** `JBOSS_HOME` pointing to the root folder of that instance.
2. If you have **multiple instances of WildFly/JBoss** running on that machine, you can **run command** `set JBOSS=[replace this with target instance's root folder path]` **and then** run the **command you mentioned**.

Hope that helps.